# Facing Problems in React Installation In windows10

Tags: reactjs, installation

I previously installed node.js and mongodb and worked with it in vscode..Now I tried to install react but it is showing me error everytime...tried many utube tutorials..nothing worked...pls help

```
C:\Windows\system32> cd c:\reactjs

c:\Reactjs>npm init react-app my-app
'RABI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\34e2c46f4bd11602\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.15.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path c:\Reactjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app my-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SUSMITA & RABI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-06T07_00_49_938Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the evidence

> 'RABI\AppData\Local\npm-cache...'

and

> 'C:\Users\SUSMITA & RABI\AppData\Local\npm-cache...'

I'd guess that Npm isn't quite compatible with the `&` sign in your username (which is a special character in shells).

You may need to use another user with no `&` in the username, unless there's some workaround.

Comment: Hi it worked.Thank you very much...i installed react but one thing is not working..tried my level best...nodemon is not working like before in vs code..insalled globally many times..can you help me with that pls?? it is showing like this is vs code  -------------------PS F:\Node Demo1\MongoDb> nodemon .\read.js
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,  
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.    
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon .\read.js
+ ~~~

Comment: That's a different error, probably related to the PATH setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
 npx create-react-app app-name
```

Comment: hi used this and it is showing error

Comment: Whats the error in this command ?

Comment: C:\Users\SUSMITA & RABI>npx create-react-app my-app
'RABI\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;

Comment: while installing node did you add the same in environment variables ?

Comment: sir i found this in the path   C:\Program Files\nodejs\     C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin